# Связка цикла с кнопкой в боте

Tags: python, aiogram, бот, while

Есть такой цикл

```
    count = 0
    while True:
        count += 1
        if quantitystr > count and message.text == 'Следующий вопрос' :
            
            await message.answer(f'<b>{clear_text(qwestion[count])}</b>\n\n'
                                     f'<i>(нажми на  и запиши видеоответ)</i>', reply_markup=nav.qwestionMenu_2,
                                     parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML)
            bodynowqwestion = qwestion[count]
            await FSMdonload.video.set()
        
        else:
            break
```

На Следующий вопрос завязана кнопка в боте, но проблема в том, что message.text то не меняется и не обнуляется, цикл мне все вопросы разом строчит, а нужно по кнопке по одному выдавать.
Как сделать?

Comment: А что вы в целом хотите сделать? У меня есть ощущение что вы делаете что-то не то

Comment: Есть бд со списком вопросов, по кнопке следущий нужно присылать вопросы по одному.

Comment: Какой тип кнопок?

Comment: Текстовый, не инлайн

Comment: Можете больше кода дать?